# Specifying positive solutions for a system of non-linear equations

Tags: matlab

I want to solve a system of non-linear equations in matlab  such that the solutions are positive. Can I specify in matlab that I want positive solutions for unknown variables? How?

Comment: Is your problem that the system of equations permits multiple solutions, and sometimes you get solutions where some variables are negative?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can define the variables with [syms](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/toolbox/symbolic/syms.html) like:

```
syms x y positive
```

and those variables are constained to be positive. See [fsolve](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/toolbox/optim/ug/fsolve.html) for how to find the solution after you have define the constraints on variables.